# Change app-header background image using databinding

Tags: polymer, background-image

I'm newbie to web, and sorry for not good English.
But I have question.

I want to change Polymer's app-header element background image using databinding.
I want to show different header image whenever router's page changed.
But this code is not working.
I don't know how to pick and manipulate css of background-image.

```
<style>
    ...
    --app-header-background-front-layer: {
        /*This line is working*/
        /*background-image: url(/images/tmp/header_image_1.png);*/

        /*This line is NOT working*/
        background-image: url([[headerImageUrl]]);
        background-position: left center;
    };
    ...
</style>

<script>
    ...
    properties: {
        ...
        headerImageUrl: {
            type: String,
            value: "/images/tmp/header_image_1.png"
        }
        ...
    },
    ...
<script>
```

---

I got my solution.
Niklas Lang gave me a hint.
Here is my code.

```
<style>
    ...
    :host {
        ...
        /*this custom css property could be changed whenever I want */
        --header-image: url(/images/tmp/header_image_1.png);
        ...
    }
    ...
    --app-header-background-front-layer: {
        background-image: var(--header-image);
        background-position: left center;
    };
    ...
</style>

<script>
    ...
    // this function called when router's page value is changed.
    setHeader: function () {
        switch (this.page) {
            case blabla1:
                this.customStyle['--header-image'] = 'url(/images/tmp/header_image_1.png)';
                this.updateStyles();
                break;
            case blabla2:
                this.customStyle['--header-image'] = 'url(/images/tmp/header_image_2.png)';
                this.updateStyles();
                break;
            case blabla3:
                this.customStyle['--header-image'] = 'url(/images/tmp/header_image_2.png)';
                this.updateStyles();
            default :
                break;
        }
    },
    ...
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the actual Element in your style.
When you make use of Polymer mixin you should apply it to the corresponding  Element, in your case the app-header.

```
app-header {
  --app-header-background-front-layer: {
    background-image: url();
  };
}
```

However, i am not sure if it is even possible to bind to your style.
What you could try is to bind to Inline style.
In the Polymer documentation they call it [Bind to a target attribute](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding)

```
<div style$="color: {{myColor}};">
```

But in your case I am not entirely sure how this is supposed to work as you are applying mixin and not just a single style value.

Comment: Thank you so much.
This isn't exact answer what I want.
But you gave me a big hint.

I'll add my solution on my article.